# How to Retrieve Multiple values from Firebase Database ?(JOIN from multiple nodes)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: This is my database]

hello masters,
this is something new and not questioned before.

i want to get values from firebase database something like JOIN in SQL.

**Q. it is possible to fetch values from diff/multiple nodes?**

as you see in above image...

for Ex. get values of  **msgs,recNm,sendrNm,time,msessage** from **11_12** by comparing **recNm/sendrNm** value of of **11** from **profile_pics**.

Depending on to the user like 11/12 fetch the img_url and related information(like messages,time,etc..).

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just call twice to ListenerForSignleValueEvent, when onDataChange called for the first one, run the other one and use both, for Example:

```
    DatabaseReference firstRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(FIRSTREFKEY);

    firstRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot Ref1dataSnapshot) {

    DatabaseReference secondRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(SECONDREFKEY);
    secondRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot Ref2dataSnapshot) {      

        **work here with both nodes values** (Ref1dataSnapshot and Ref2dataSnapshot)

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {            }        });
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {         
}});
```

Comment: Ok, let me know when you have any result.